# How to configure ssh config host for two different ports

Tags: ssh

I have a host that I need to connect to via SSH both internally on a private network (on port 22) as well as externally (on port 2222). For example the private host is 192.168.1.1 port 22 and the public host is 1.2.3.4 port 2222.

I am successfully using the `Match exec` directive with `nc -z -w 1 %h %p`) to successfully ProxyJump *through* this host to other hosts internally but in this case I want to establish a direct session to this host to access my internal git repositories which are hosted on this server. IOW, I would like `git remote` to use a single, static host line instead of one for internal and another for external.

How can I configure my personal ~/.ssh/ssh_config to connect directly to this host using the correct hostname/port based on my network location (internal vs external).

Comment: This is handled in the router. It's called Port Forwarding. You can set the WAN port (2222) and redirect it to the LAN port 22.